# How do I create Navbar Drawer Menu in android?

Tags: java, android

I found many solutions for my problem. But problem is that the solution is for **activity_main.xml**. I have created my own layout **myOwnLayout** programmatically and set **setContentView(myOwnLayout)**. So, how do I add Navbar Drawer to **myOwnLayout**.

I'm new in android developing. Help me with some demo codes. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you go to youtube? that'll be helpful too for your developing skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like `myOwnLayout` is the layout for your activity. It's likely that the layout file for the Navigation Bar you want to add will be its own layout, not something you would add to `myOwnLayout`. And that makes sense, because the Navigation Bar is its own thing- it should have its own layout too. In general, each screen will usually get its own layout.

I suggest looking at tutorials, as pointed out in a comment. Fortunately, Android Studio comes with this capability built in. If you create a new project, eventually you will hit a screen that shows different kinds of basic activities you can start with. One of them is called `Navigation Drawer Activity`, and it should help you out quite a bit if you take the time to go through the code. In fact, you should be able to copy/paste your code into that new activity and get it to work without too much difficulty.